# setting the django project with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to set up celery with Django on my development server, running on ubuntu. Following are changes i made.

**init.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import task
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'samplecelery.settings')


app = Celery('samplecelery')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y
```

when i run the command to check the worker for samplecelery

celery -A sampleceleryworker -l info

app=Celery(samplecelery)

It tells me the app is not installed. Any thoughts on what might have gone wrong in this setup?can anyone please help me.....
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Celery'

Comment: You are missing an import for Celery in celery.py

Comment: But now i'm getting this following error in tasks.py is

from Celery import shared_task
ImportError: No module named 'Celery'

Comment: Plz update your code above with what you have now so I can see it.

Comment: i have updated the code. when i run the celery worker i'm getting this following error.. 
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY') TypeError: config_from_object() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace' and also i'm new to this how to call the tasks.

Comment: What version of celery are you using? Can you check with pip freeze?

Comment: only newer version of celery has the argument 'namespace'.however,if you are using dj-celery, it delivers a older version of celery with it.you can use 'pip uninstall celery' to uninstall the wrong version and re-install it with 'pip install celery'.

Comment: I am new to celery how can I use rest framework.can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 1):

to resolve this error

> TypeError: config_from_object() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'namespace'

the solution is [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3107).you need to:

```
pip install celery==4.2.0
```